# nested for loop in oracle to find similarity optimize

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables both has same value but bot are from different source.

```
Table 1
------------
ID  Title
1   Introduction to Science
2   Introduction to C
3   Let is C
4   C
5   Java

Table 2
------------------------
ID  Title
a   Intro to Science
b   Intro to C
c   Let is C
d   C
e   Java
```

I want to compare all the title in table 1 with title in table 2 and find the similarity match.

I Have used the built-in function in orcale "**UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity (LS_Title, LSO_Title)**;"

Script:

```
DECLARE
LS_count      NUMBER;
LSO_count     NUMBER;
percentage    NUMBER;
LS_Title      VARCHAR2 (4000);
LSO_Title     VARCHAR2 (4000);
LS_CPNT_ID    VARCHAR2 (64);
LSO_CPNT_ID   VARCHAR2 (64);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO LS_count FROM tbl_zim_item;
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO LSO_count FROM tbl_zim_lso_item;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value of a: ' || LS_count);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value of a: ' || LSO_count);
FOR i IN 1 .. LS_count
LOOP
  SELECT cpnt_title
    INTO LS_Title
    FROM tbl_zim_item
   WHERE iden = i;

  SELECT cpnt_id
    INTO LS_CPNT_ID
    FROM tbl_zim_item
   WHERE iden = i;

  FOR j IN 1 .. lso_count
  LOOP
     SELECT cpnt_title
       INTO LSO_Title
       FROM tbl_zim_lso_item
      WHERE iden = j;

     SELECT cpnt_id
       INTO LSO_CPNT_ID
       FROM tbl_zim_lso_item
      WHERE iden = j;

     percentage :=
        UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity (LS_Title, LSO_Title);

     IF percentage > 50
     THEN
        INSERT INTO title_sim
             VALUES (ls_cpnt_id,
                     ls_title,
                     lso_cpnt_id,
                     lso_title,
                     percentage);
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

This is running for more than 15 hours. Kindly provide a better solution.
Note : My table 1 has 20000 records and table 2 has 10000 records.

Comment: Is cpnt_title unique? Else couldn't you spare some work by not revalidating titles you have already worked on?

Comment: Shouldn't the third title be "Let us C" instead of "Let is C" :)  ?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't need all of the looping and row-by-row lookups since SQL can do cross joins. Therefore my first try would be just:

```
insert into title_sim
     ( columns... )
select ls_cpnt_id
     , ls_title
     , lso_cpnt_id
     , lso_title
     , percentage
from   ( select i.cpnt_id     as ls_cpnt_id
              , i.cpnt_title  as ls_title
              , li.cpnt_id    as lso_cpnt_id
              , li.cpnt_title as lso_title
              , case  -- Using Boneist's suggestion:
                    when i.cpnt_title = li.cpnt_title then 100
                    else utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(i.cpnt_title, li.cpnt_title)
                end as percentage
         from   tbl_zim_item i
                cross join tbl_zim_lso_item li )
where  percentage > 50;
```

If there is much repetition in the titles, you might benefit from some scalar subquery caching by wrapping the `utl_match.edit_distance_similarity` function in a `( select ... from dual )`.

If the titles are often exactly the same and assuming in those cases percentage should be 100%, you might avoid calling the function when the titles are an exact match:

```
begin
    select count(*) into ls_count from tbl_zim_item;
    select count(*) into lso_count from tbl_zim_lso_item;

    dbms_output.put_line('tbl_zim_item contains ' || ls_count || ' rows.');
    dbms_output.put_line('tbl_zim_lso_item contains ' || lso_count || ' rows.');

    for r in (
        select i.cpnt_id     as ls_cpnt_id
             , i.cpnt_title  as ls_title
             , li.cpnt_id    as lso_cpnt_id
             , li.cpnt_title as lso_title
             , case
                   when i.cpnt_title = li.cpnt_title then 100 else 0
               end as percentage
        from   tbl_zim_item i
               cross join tbl_zim_lso_item li
    )
    loop
        if r.percentage < 100 then
            r.percentage := utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(r.ls_title, r.lso_title);
        end if;

        if r.percentage > 50 then
            insert into title_sim (columns...)
            values
            ( ls_cpnt_id
            , ls_title
            , lso_cpnt_id
            , lso_title
            , percentage );
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Couldn't you have a case statement in your original cross-joined query to decide whether to call the match function or not, rather than needing to loop through the rows? Something like `case when i.cpnt_title = li.cpnt_title then 100 else utl_match.edit_distance_similarity(i.cpnt_title, li.cpnt_title) end as percentage`?

Comment: @Boneist - Added :)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson if there are 20000 record in table 1 and 10000 record in table 2. How long it will take for my query to execute?

Comment: @Boneist in most case title does not match 100%

Comment: @AmareshKarnan if you want to know how long the query will take, why don't you run it and find out for yourself? We don't have a copy of your database or know what spec server it's running on, etc etc

Comment: Even if I took time out of my day to mock up sample data and run your performance tests for you, this wouldn't tell you how long it will take on your system with your data. Now would be a good time for you to tell us which of the proposed approaches worked best.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping through all the data, I'd merely join the two tables together, eg:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'Introduction to Science' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 ID, 'Introduction to C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 ID, 'Let is C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 ID, 'C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 5 ID, 'Java' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 6 ID, 'Oracle for Newbies' title FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 'a' ID, 'Intro to Science' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'b' ID, 'Intro to C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'c' ID, 'Let is C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'd' ID, 'C' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'e' ID, 'Java' title FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'f' ID, 'PL/SQL rocks!' title FROM dual)
SELECT t1.title t1_title,
       t2.title t2_title,
       UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(t1.title, t2.title)
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t2 ON UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(t1.title, t2.title) > 50;

T1_TITLE                T2_TITLE         UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILA
----------------------- ---------------- ------------------------------
Introduction to Science Intro to Science                             70
Introduction to C       Intro to C                                   59
Let is C                Let is C                                    100
C                       C                                           100
Java                    Java                                        100
```

By doing that, you can then reduce the whole thing to a single DML statement, something like:

```
INSERT INTO title_sim (t1_id,
                       t1_title,
                       t2_id,
                       t2_title,
                       percentage)
SELECT t1.id t1_id,
       t1.title t1_title,
       t2.id t2_id,
       t2.title t2_title,
       UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(t1.title, t2.title) percentage
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t2 ON UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(t1.title, t2.title) > 50;
```

which ought to be a good deal faster than your row-by-row attempt, particularly as you are unnecessarily selecting from each table twice.

As an aside, you know that you can select multiple columns into multiple variables in the same query, right?

So instead of having:

```
SELECT cpnt_title
  INTO LS_Title
  FROM tbl_zim_item
 WHERE iden = i;

SELECT cpnt_id
  INTO LS_CPNT_ID
  FROM tbl_zim_item
 WHERE iden = i;
```

you could instead do:

```
SELECT cpnt_title, cpnt_id
  INTO LS_Title, LS_CPNT_ID
  FROM tbl_zim_item
 WHERE iden = i;
```

Comment: I want all the record in table 1 to compared with table 2 . Will this do that? Eg. if there are 10 record in each table it should be compared 10*10 times and give me result.

Comment: @AmareshKarnan Yes, it will.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will execute and provide you an update. :)

Comment: Thank you this worked and it took around 1 hr and 30 mins to execute.

Comment: I would expect that the first insert statement in William's answer would be slightly faster, since it's not running the function when the two titles are equal. Can you test that statement too and tell us how long it took, please?

Comment: out of those 20000 and 100 records only one matched 100% so I don't think there will be a big difference.

Comment: Ooh, probably not, then! *{:-)

Comment: @Boniest Can you please help me on the below? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805398/join-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/intersect.php

this will give you data which is similar in both queries

```
 select title from table_1 
 intersect 
 select title from table_2
```

Comment: No, that will give you data that is the same in both tables, **not** similar.