# JOIN TABLE IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have a table with 100000 records and I get 97000 records as part of this below query how to get the remaining 30000 records. I tried not equal to `'H.RESOURCE_ID <> SQ.CPNT_OG_ID'` but not getting correct data?

```
SELECT H.pernr AS "STUD_ID",
       SQ.CPNT_TYP_ID,
       SQ.CPNT_ID,
       TO_CHAR (SQ.REV_DTE, 'MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS REV_DTE,
       CASE                                                           --WAIVED
          WHEN sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'VIDEO' AND enrollment_status = 'Complete'
          THEN
             'VIDEO-COMPLETE'
          WHEN sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'VIDEO' AND enrollment_status <> 'Complete'
          THEN
             'VIDEO-WAIVED'
          WHEN     sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'CERTIFICATION'
               AND enrollment_status = 'Complete'
          THEN
             'CERT-COMPLETE'
          WHEN     sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'CERTIFICATION'
               AND enrollment_status <> 'Complete'
          THEN
             'CERT-WAIVED'
          WHEN sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'CDOC' AND enrollment_status = 'Complete'
          THEN
             'CDOC-COMPLETE'
          WHEN sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'CDOC' AND enrollment_status <> 'Complete'
          THEN
             'CDOC-WAIVED'
          WHEN     sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'ELEARNING'
               AND enrollment_status = 'Complete'
          THEN
             'Elearning-COMPLETE-PASSED'
          WHEN     sq.CPNT_TYP_ID = 'ELEARNING'
               AND enrollment_status <> 'Complete'
          THEN
             'Elearning-WAIVED'
          ELSE
             NULL
       END
          "CMPL_STAT_ID",
       TO_CHAR (H.COMPLETION_DATE, 'MON-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          AS COMPLETION_DATE,
       'RECORD_Admin'
          AS "ESIG_MEANING_CODE_ID",
       NULL                                           AS "LST_UPD_USR",
       sq.rev_num                                     AS "REV_NUM",
       'LEARNSHARE'                                   AS "COMMENTS"
  FROM ZB_USR_HISTORY_NEW H
       JOIN
       (SELECT DISTINCT CPNT_ID,
                        CPNT_TYP_ID,
                        CPNT_OG_ID,
                        REV_DTE,
                        REV_NUM,
                        CPNT_COURSE_NUM
          FROM TBL_ZIM_ITEM_new
         WHERE VALID = '1' AND app_id LIKE '%en-us%' OR LENGTH (app_id) < 9)
       SQ
          ON (H.RESOURCE_ID = SQ.CPNT_OG_ID);
```

Comment: Did you try `left join`?

Comment: The simplest way is to get on of your 'missing' 3000 records and check that the TBL_ZIM_ITEM_new table has a record for the RESOURCE_ID. If it does check the VALID and APP_ID fields of that row. The conditions of your join are very straightforward it should be a quick, easy task.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN. You can use LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN in SQL in order to also fetch the record that do not satisfy the join condition. The columns selected in the non-existing row will be NULL.

Comment: I getting more than 3000 records if I use LEFT OR RIGHT join

Comment: @Bonniest HI can you find anything?